# image uploading plugin (php jquery flash)

Tags: php, jquery, image-manipulation, image-uploading

- what's the best plugin for image uploading using php/jquery?
  it should have a progressbar and display information like percent, speed and such.
- how to do image-resizing after uploading? i'd also like to embed a watermark image

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i find Uploadify very good.

http://www.uploadify.com/

Regarding watermarking images I'd use Perls GD or ImageMagik modules:

http://metacpan.org/pod/GD

https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Magick

Answer (score 1):

There are many classes to resize images

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1450-PHP-Resize-image-from-files-in-different-formats-.html